# Pass array argument to link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to pass an array value to the `link_to` function in rails. The link url needs to be http://domain.com/?example[item]=value

I've tried with this code, but it doesn't work.

```
link_to example_path(example[item]: value)
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: You're actually passing a hash parameter rather than an array parameter. An array parameter would just have `example[]` rather than including the `item` mapping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
link_to "example", example_path(example: {item: value})
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the new hash syntax, but with the old one you can try:

```
link_to "example", example_path(:'example[item]' => value)
```

Comment: @spas: what  does `:` before `'example...`?